# How to count territory of Go game in general C++ code?

Tags: c++

I'm literally a fresh leaner of programming and I started with C++, and I successfully program simple game like Tic-Tac-Toe but it seems that I struggle a lot in  Go Game since it's just black army and white army. And yeah it's not easy, just for me maybe, I stuck at counting territory, I just can't imagine how to count it....

Comment: Take a look at [sensei's library](http://senseis.xmp.net/?ComputerGoAlgorithms). You may find it interesting

Comment: I suggest looking at the [Logical Rules of Go](http://tromp.github.io/go.html).

Comment: Here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/20375/13035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would go about it, without much thought. I presume you're asking about scoring the definite territory at the end of the game, and not trying to score a position's likely territory during a game (which is a MUCH harder problem even conceptually).

First, in the outer loop, I would scan for empty positions, left-to-right top-to-bottom

When I find one, I would fill it in with a territory ID (instead of white or black), and for each adjacent empty I would recursively repeat the process. Filling it with a territory ID ensures you don't redo the same square. You could use a single value, but I think an ID will make debugging easier!

As I do this, I would count track whether I have seen a white or black boundary. If, when I run out of empty spaces, it is only bordered by white or black, I would add the count of this territory to the total for that side. If both, it is uncaptured.

You only consider running out of empty space, when the topmost recursion run has no more adjacent empties to examine. You can do this by having each recursion return the state -- white, black, or disputed. If all the recursions on empty neighbors are the same as for this position, return that value; otherwise return disputed. If the top pass returns black or white, it's captured territory.

Basically, one level of 2D iteration looking for empty, and recursion within each territory, marking and counting/evaluating.

Comment: Thanks for the help, right on my question and very detail! As I said i'm a fresh learner so I don't actually know what to learn to do that. Can you tell me? And maybe suggest a website to learn for it would be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Counting territory in GO is an especially hard problem, and generations of developers have tried to solve it. I do not recommend to try to program that as a beginner - it is probably a multi-month project for experienced developers.

No wonder you struggle with that.

Comment: It may not be so hard as that, depending on what he is trying to do.

Scoring the end of the game should only be an hour or so for an experienced programmer. Scoring for evaluating strategy, on the other hand, is a task for an experienced programmer who is also very good at Go!